# How to use SQL Joins and Selects to get results from a third table that matches the first two?

Tags: sql

I have a Join statement on two tables(Table 1 and 2), which returns the City and State. I have another table(Table 3) which contains columns like Name, City, State, Country. I want to fetch all the rows from Table 3 whose City and State Columns matches with the rows of the Join result.

```
Select * from 3rdTable where City='' AND State='';
```

Result from Join is like

```
 - City | State
 - A    | B
 - C    | D
 - E    | F
```

Example Result if only 1 row of the 3rd table matches

```
 - C    |  D
```

How can this be done?

Comment: could you share your code? It is not clear right now

Comment: I have edited the question, hope its clear now...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the joined table as a sub table in 3rdTable to create a where clause as follows;

```
select * 
from 3rdTable 
where City+'|'+State= (select a.City+'|'+b.State 
                       from a 
                       inner join b 
                         on a.x=b.y)
```

Buy concatenating the fields, you can create a single equality to the joined subquery

Comment: It worked after changing = to IN                                           "select * from 3rdTable where City+'|'+State=(select a.City+'|'+b.State from a inner join b on a.x=b.y)"

Comment: Ok, I hope my  response is a step in the right direction, and the problem is now solver right?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure about the joins, we have inner join, Left join, right join and outer join; maybe knowing the difference can help you to answer your question.
and also the code is not clear :)

Comment: this is not an answer but a suggestion or a comment. its better placed there

Answer (score 0):

Just join in the 3rd table...

IF we assume table1 has both city and state in it...

```
SELECT A.City, A.State
FROM Table1 A
INNER JOIN table2 B
 on A.PK = B.A_FK
INNER JOIN table3 C
  on A.City = C.City
 and A.State = C.State
```

This is the nature of an inner join: Include all rows from all tables where the joined data matches.

If you use  an OUTER join (left, right, full outer) then you get all records from one table and only those that match in the others, or full outer all records from all tables aligned where they match.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help you:

```
SELECT T3.* 
FROM
table_1_2_join T12 /* replace this placeholder table with the select statement that joins your 2 tables */
JOIN table_3 T3 ON T3.City = T12.city AND T3.state = T12.state
```

Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table3 t3 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT city, 
                          state 
                   FROM   table1 T1 
                          JOIN table2 t2 
                            ON t1.id = t2.id) a1 
               ON t3.city = a1.city 
                  AND t3.state = a1.state
```